# SQL to filter by multiple criteria including containment in string list

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, scripting, sql-scripts

so i have a table lets say call it "tbl.items" and there is a column "title" in "tbl.items" i want to loop through each row and for each "title" in "tbl.items" i want to do following:
*the column has the datatype nvarchar(max) and contains a string...*

1. filter the string to remove words like in,out, where etc (stopwords)
2. compare the rest of the string to a predefined list and if there is a match perform some action which involves inserting data in other tables as well..

the problem is im ignotent when it comes to writing T-sql scripts, plz help and guide me how can i achieve this? 
whether it can be achieved by writing a sql script??
 or i have to develope a console application in c# or anyother language??

im using mssql server 2008

thanks in advance

Comment: This could be done really simple with linq2sql, though that might be a bit overkill.

Comment: have you constructed a function or procedure? how about a trigger?  are you stuck on function creation? or trigger logic?  you are describing all typical sql stuff - no c# required

Comment: It could be done with some ugly nested replace()s in sql ... this is mysql, but you get the idea: "where replace(replace(replace( name, 'the', ''), 'by', ''), 'where', '') like '%test%'" ... probably better to use another language or to build a second table with reduced strings.

Comment: @Alxandr ... yup Linq2sql is also under consideration but i was hoping to learn some sql scripting etc ..

Comment: @Randy... thats the wholepoint of confusion u can say... i havent used functions and procedures i know that they exist and what they do but i never used then in real so i was confused to how and what to use ... and yup im stuck on logic part too ...

Comment: Could you change the title of this question something more specific. For example, "SQL to filter by multiple criteria including containment in string list" would be a start.

Comment: @3nigma Cheers, just more likely to get hit by searches now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a few things.  First, look up SQL Server's syntax for functions, and write something like this:

```
-- Warning! Code written off the top of my head,
-- don't expect this to work w/copy-n-paste
create function removeStrings(@input nvarchar(4000))
as begin
    -- We're being kind of simple-minded and using strings
    -- instead of regular expressions, so we are assuming a
    -- a space before and after each word.  This makes this work better:
    @input = ' ' + @input

    -- Big list of replaces
    @input = replace(' in ','',@input)
    @input = replace(' out ','',@input)
    --- more replaces...
end
```

Then you need your list of matches in a table, call this "predefined" with a column "matchString".

Then you can retrieve the matching rows with:

```
select p.matchString
  from items i
  join predefined p 
    on removeStrings(i.title) = p.matchString
```

Once you have those individual pieces working, I suggest a new question on what particular process you may be doing with them.

Warning: Not knowing how many rows you have or how often you have to do this (every time a user saves something?  Once/day?), this will not exactly be zippy, if you know what I mean.  So once you have these building blocks in hand, there may also be a follow-up question for how and when to do it.

Comment: tnx alot ur answer gave me something to work on actually i have thousands of rows in the table and i was hoping that i would be able to do it with simple plain sql script... i'll give it a shot with functions ... tell me one thing is it possible to do it with cursors?? ... tnx again for ur help...

Comment: @3nigma you can define a cursor yes and process through the rows if necessary.  But like i said, I recommend making sure you've got these core elements down, then make a new question just about how to process it efficiently.

Comment: okz tnx now im divin into the functions... will ost back the prog... tnx everybody...

Comment: finally i managed to write the solution ... u gave me kick start so im gonna accept ur answer...